# How to config and get value in plugin emqx

Tags: java, mqtt, erl, emqx

i'm using [emqx v5](https://github.com/emqx/emqx) to pub,sub, connect, v.v.. Meanwhile, I've been developing my plugin and plugin template from [this](https://github.com/emqx/emqx-plugin-template).

Normally, in emqx-plugin-template.erl, i declare my constant like this

[image]

and i can use it from all funtion in this file. But now i want to save them in pri/config.hocon and get them to use similarly.
This is structure of plugin

[image]

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get them out and how to declare them so I can use them in as many functions as before. Please guide me.

I try: hocon:load(file name) and maps:get(key, Config) but is is match to a file in emqx/_build/emqx/rel/emqx/config.hocon (this is server emqx)..ít's work but that's not what I want because the author of the template already has pri/config.hocon available and i just want to touch my plugin not eqmx server

Answer (score 0):

There are three options

1. Put the config somewhere outside of `emqx` release directory, and use absolute path in the `hocon:load` call
2. Call `code:priv_dir(emqx_plugin_messenger)` to get the path of your app's `priv` directory
3. Put the config in `EMQX data/` directory, and call `emqx:data_dir()` to get it.